# Run Javascript every time ajax request is completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div on a page onto which new contents are added using ajax calls.
below that div i have a Javascript.

Now i want that javascript to execute everytime an ajax call is completed and contents gets added to the div.

So for example: if i have something like

```
<div class="results">
     blah blah blah(more contents added after each ajax call)
</div>
<script id="adjust" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

I want the script with id adjust to execute everytime ajax call is done.

Comment: and how looks like your `myscript.js` code?

Comment: Why not add a callback function to the Ajax request? You can't simply execute `myscript.js`. Add a function to execute instead.

Comment: myscript.js has some functions in it .. that's it

Comment: You're going to have to tell us what the functions are, what they do, and what their arguments are, or simply provide the code. "some functions" is nowhere near descriptive enough.

Answer (score 4):

For jQuery Ajax you have the complete-callback. Pass a reference to the function you want to execute when the Ajax-call completes.

```
$.ajax({
   // Your other options here
   complete: functionToCall
});
```

It can also be done like this:

```
$.ajax({ /* Your options */ }).done(functionToCall);
```

More on the various event that occur during an AJAX-call is available [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).